# Firebase queries not working on Android even though the reference retrieves data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter my Firebase data, my dataset is complex but here is a sample. I am able to retrieve data just fine but I am unable to filter that data any further using the Firebase queries. Here is a sample dataset:

[image]

Here is my query:

```
private double locStart;
private double locEnd;
Firebase mRef;
Firebase mRef1;

    mRef = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/");
mRef1 = mRef.child("test");

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final Inputs inputs = (Inputs) intent.getSerializableExtra("inputs");

    locStart = inputs.getLocLat() - 0.008983;
    locEnd = inputs.getLocLat() + 0.008983;

    Query filterData = mRef1.orderByChild("locLat").startAt(locStart).endAt(locEnd);

    filterData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Match matchd = dataSnapshot.getValue(Match.class);
            Offer.setText(matchd.getfbName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The reference mRef1 retrieves data perfectly, its only when I apply the query to it is when it retrieves null values, the data certainly matches the query, I have even hard coded the values but that does not seem to work either.

Am I missing something I should have setup on the Firebase console? I did setup an index and that solved a warning in my log which was suggesting me to set one up on the field meaning that Firebase is recognising the field and the index as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase queries return a subset of the child nodes in a list.

So if you have a list of locations:

```
locations: {
  location1: { lat: 42.010185, lon: -33.010185 },
  location2: { lat: -11.19645, lon:  52.461219 },
  location3: { lat: 33.14518,  lon: -11.128746 }
}
```

You could query the locations with:

```
ref.child("locations").orderByChild("lat").startAt(-12.0).endAt(-10)
```

Your data is missing a level: you're querying `test`, but are missing the `location1`, `location2`, `location3` level that I have under it. If you add such a level, your query will be able to match the child.

Your next problem is likely going to be that Firebase Database queries can only order by/filter on a single property. That means that for geo-queries, you can currently only filter on longitude *or* on latitude, which makes for only half a geo-query. I recommend that you look into [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java), which is our library for geo-querying. It combines latitude and longitude of each item into a single [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) value, which can then be queried.

Comment: Thanks Frank. You were absolutely right, it was the way I entered data into Firebase and also the way in which I was retrieving the data with the assumption that there will only be one record, just used a for loop to loop through the dataSnapshot and I was just fine. Thanks for the help. 

Also, if I may ask you, is there any piece of code or Git repo out there to save the data in the format you suggested?

Comment: I provided a link to Geofire, a library that does precisely that.

Comment: I did actually read through it but I was not sure how I can push the rest of the data along with the location. I know I need to change both the way the data is inputted and retrieved but is there a way to input the rest of my data along with the Geofire location that you would know of?