# How to get value from StartAt specifirc position and EndAt specific position in Firebase Android Query

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble getting data from my database.

**My database:**
[image]

**My code:**

```
 Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes").startAt(5).endAt(10);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        String authorName = data.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                        String quoteGiven = data.child("Quote").getValue().toString();
                        name.setText("- " + authorName);
                        quote.setText(quoteGiven);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading Quote failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I want to get my data from the 5th child to the 10th child.

**I've tried:**

[Select random entry from Firebase Realtime Database in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399597/select-random-entry-from-firebase-realtime-database-in-java)

[get random value android firebase java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154966/get-random-value-android-firebase-java/28155162)

[Firebase queries not working on Android even though the reference retrieves data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569846/firebase-queries-not-working-on-android-even-though-the-reference-retrieves-data)

However, the is only showing the hard-coded text I left and not the text from the database?

can anyone help me, I am not sure where i went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `orderByKey()`:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes").orderByKey().startAt(String.valueOf(5)).endAt(String.valueOf(10));
```

This should give you all the data from the 5th key to the 10th in your database.

From the docs:

> `orderByKey()`
>
> Order results by child keys

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: I've added, this and it was still not showing any data. I then added a toast message on the for loop and it did not trigger, am i doing something wrong in the event listener as its not going into the for loop??

Comment: Can u add a log before the for loop, also remove startat and endAt, and test it

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported

Comment: fixed it, ```FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes").orderByKey().startAt(String.valueOf(5)).endAt(String.valueOf(10));```

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes").startAt(5).endAt(10);
```

to

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Quotes")
    .orderByKey().startAt("5").endAt("10");
```

The keys that you pass to the `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods, should always be strings and **not** numbers.